# "ERROR 1282 in glViewport" when used in async/thread

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm seeing "ERROR 1282 in glViewport" in my terminal whne I call `glViewport` from inside `glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback`. Not sure why, I think it should be firing from the correct context, but I'm not sure. It worked fine before I tried to move my gameloop into a thread.

Here's the code, I tried to trim out the extraneous stuff:

```cpp
const int winWidth = 800;
const int winHeight = 600;

absl::Status glfwMain() {
    gl::setOpenGlVersion(4, 6, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    ASSIGN_OR_RETURN(GLFWwindow * window, gl::createWindow(winWidth, winHeight, "mario4ever"))

    std::atomic<bool> breakLoop = false;
    auto gameLoop = std::async(std::launch::async, [&window, &breakLoop]() {
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress)) {
            return absl::InternalError("Failed to initialize GLAD");
        }
        
        /* snip */

        glViewport(0, 0, winWidth, winHeight);
        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, [](GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height) {
            std::cerr << "glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback" << std::endl;
            glViewport(0, 0, width, height);   // <----- error fires here
        });

        while (!breakLoop) {
            draw(window);
        }

        /* snip */

        return absl::OkStatus();
    });


    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        processInput(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    breakLoop = true;
    return gameLoop.get();

    return absl::OkStatus();
}

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    auto status = glfwMain();
    glfwTerminate();
    if (!status.ok()) {
        std::cerr << status << std::endl;
    }
    return status.raw_code();
}
```

Whether I put the `glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback` inside the `std::async` or outside doesn't seem to make a difference.

What's the problem?

---

[This tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Debugging) says error `1282` is `GL_INVALID_VALUE` and according to [these docs](http://docs.gl/gl4/glViewport) that should happen only when "either width or height is negative".

I checked the width and height that the callback is giving me and neither is negative. They're about what I'd expect.

---

Tried adding a mutex:

```cpp
std::mutex drawMutex;

void draw(GLFWwindow *window) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(drawMutex);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}

...

        // inside `std::async` callback:
        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, [](GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(drawMutex);
            glViewport(0, 0, width, height);  
        });
```

Comment: At first glance I was sure this was caused by  `glViewport()` being invoked in the main thread at a "random" time from OpenGL's pov (and it might very well be the casue of that specific crash), but there's other weird things going on here. Namely: `std::async` is being invoked with the default policy and `breakLoop` is not atomic. So wether this is running single or multi-threaded is left up to the standard library and if it is multithreaded, you have some nasty UB with `breakLoop`.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the tips. I fixed those 2 things but I'm still seeing the same error. Also crashes quite frequently when resizing, even if I take out the `glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback`.

Comment: as far as `glViewport()` is concerned an easy, if hacky fix to at least confrm that it's caused by contention would be to use a global mutex to ensure `glViewport()` is not called while `draw(window)` is in progress. A proper message queue would probably be a better solution, but that's a big refactor.

Comment: @Frank Added a mutex. I don't think that was it either :-(

Comment: @mpen The [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) is thread local. Do you have an active OpenGL Context when you call `glViewport`? - [`glfwMakeContextCurrent`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__context.html#ga1c04dc242268f827290fe40aa1c91157)

Comment: Must be my shoddy threading code...maybe I can't run `glfwWindowShouldClose` or `glfwPollEvents` or `glfwGetKey` on a different thread..

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yeah..there should be one. You can see the call to `glfwMakeContextCurrent` just under `auto gameLoop`. Unless the `glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback` is running in a different thread.

Comment: @mpen I think I can remember some weird behavior where I had to activate (make current) the context once on the main thread before I could use it in a separate thread.